# Highlighting rows when selecting radio buttons (multiple sets)

Tags: jquery, html-table, radio-button

I have a table which has multiple sets of radio button groups.
When I highlight a radio button it highlights the row fine.

The code snippet below doesn't take into account that I want to keep highlighted the radio button for the group when I select in a different group.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

```js
// highlight paragraphs for radio.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
      $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(e) {
    var rdname = $(this).attr('name');

    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.record_table tr').removeClass("highlight");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Set status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='123' name='group1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='456' name='group1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Other Options</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='412' name='group2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='654' name='group2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3rd Options</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='965' name='group3'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='963' name='group3'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZujfJ.png)

Comment: Hi, I have checked your sample code. Now, if we click the active radio button means, the active radio button was highlighted with blue color. But, you want to highlight the inactive radio button also when we click any active or inactive radio button. Right?

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply.  no. i want to leave the selected row highlighted in that group. then when i click on an option in the second group, it highlights the selected option. (so now one in group 1 is highlighted and one in group 2) and so forth.   i actually have about 12 groups with each containing between 2 and 15 entries in each radio button group.

Comment: Okay. So, If we check active radio button means, need to highlight the all group active radio buttons. Right?

Comment: hi jawahar, i've added a picture to the question on what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can find the checked radio and add class `highlight` to its parent `tr`.

```
$('.record_table tr input:checked').closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
```

```js
// highlight paragraphs for radio.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
      $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(e) {
    var rdname = $(this).attr('name');

    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.record_table tr').removeClass("highlight");
    $('.record_table tr input:checked').closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Set status</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='123' name='group1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='456' name='group1'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Other Options</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='412' name='group2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='654' name='group2'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>3rd Options</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='965' name='group3'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not active </td>
    <td> <input type='radio' id='963' name='group3'></td>
  </tr>
```